# Why don't we read about the korban tamid during the amidah?

Tags: tefilla, korban

For the Mussaf amidah, some read the actual relevant corresponding korban text (shabbat, chag etc) during the amidah itself, while for shacharit (and mincha) we dont read/mention the korban tamid at all during the amidah.

Answer (score 3):

R' Ezekiel Landau was asked this question and in a short responsum (Noda Bihuda OC 4; below) suggested that the text of the daily prayers needs to be available for use in additional voluntary prayers for those who want to offer such, while if the verses of the Tamid were included the prayer text could only be used at the standard fixed times. Musaf prayers are never offered voluntarily and thus were able to have the verses included.

> ואשר בדק לן מעלתו למה פסוקי המוספין קבעו בתפלת המוסף ופרשת התמיד לא תיקנו לומר בתפלה פסוקי התמיד. הנה בדבר זה היה לי למנוע מלהשיב כי מי הוא ואיזה הוא שיאמר מלבו טעם על דברים העומדים ברומו של עולם ואנשי כנסת הגדולה להם לבדם נפתחו שערי שמים וקבעו הכל בטעם ידוע להם ואין אתנו יודע עד מה. ואעפ"כ ע"פ פשוטן של דברים נלע"ד משום שהתפלות שנקבעו בכל יום נקבע בהם כל צרכי האדם וכל אחד בעת הצורך יפרוש כפיו בתפלה להתפלל אפילו כמה פעמים ביום וכמ"ד הלואי שיתפלל כל היום. ואפילו לדעת החולק עכ"פ אם אירע לו לחדש דבר יכול הוא לחזור ולהתפלל. ואם היו מזכירין התמיד בפירוש בתפלה לא היה אפשר להתפלל אלא שחרית וערבית ולמי שהיה נולד איזה דבר להתפלל עליו לא היה יכול להתפלל ואין כל אדם ביכלתו לחדש נוסח תפלה מלבו. ולקבוע תפלה אחרת חוץ מתפלה שבמקום התמיד לא רצו להטריח בכל יום. ולכן אף שתפלתנו נגד תמידין תקנו לא קבעו זכרון התמיד בפירוש בתפלה משא"כ בתפלת המוסף שהיא לפרקים קבעו פרשת המוספין מפורש:‏