# Signing off the bracha of 'magen Avraham' with just Avraham

Tags: blessing, shemoneh-esrei, avot-patriarch-fathers, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

In [Parshas Lech Lecha 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the pasuk famously reads:

> וְאֶֽעֶשְׂךָ֙ לְג֣וֹי גָּד֔וֹל וַאֲבָ֣רֶכְךָ֔ וַאֲגַדְּלָ֖ה שְׁמֶ֑ךָ וֶהְיֵ֖ה בְּרָכָֽה׃
>
> I will make of you a great nation, And I will bless you; I will make your name great, And you shall be a blessing.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12-17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.12.2.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) there writes:

> והיה ברכה. הַבְּרָכוֹת נְתוּנוֹת בְּיָדְךָ; עַד עַכְשָׁו הָיוּ בְיָדִי, בֵּרַכְתִּי לְאָדָם וְנֹחַ, וּמֵעַכְשָׁו אַתָּה תְבָרֵךְ אֶת אֲשֶׁר תַּחְפֹּץ (בראשית רבה). דָּבָר אַחֵר ואעשך לגוי גדול זֶה שֶׁאוֹמְרִים אֱלֹהֵי אַבְרָהָם, ואברכך זֶה שֶׁאוֹמְרִים אֱלֹהֵי יִצְחָק, ואגדלה שמך זֶה שֶׁאוֹמְרִים אֱלֹהֵי יַעֲקֹב. יָכוֹל יִהְיוּ חוֹתְמִין בְּכֻלָּן, תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר וֶהְיֵה בְּרָכָה, **בְּךָ חוֹתְמִין וְלֹא בָהֶם**
>
> והיה ברכה AND BE THOU A BLESSING — Blessings are entrusted to you; hitherto they were in My power — I blessed Adam and Noah — but from now on you shall bless whomsoever you wish ([Genesis Rabbah 39:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.39.11?lang=bi)) Another explanation is: AND I WILL MAKE THEE A GREAT NATION, this alludes to the fact that we say in our prayer “God of Abraham”; AND I WILL BLESS THEE — that we say, “God of Isaac”; AND I WILL MAKE THY NAME GREAT — that we say, “God of Jacob”. One might think that we should conclude the benediction in which these invocations are recited by mentioning again the names of all the patriarchs — the text therefore states “Be thou a blessing” meaning, **with you (i.e. with your name only) shall they conclude the benediction and not with them (their names)** ([Pesachim 117b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.117b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). (Sefaria translation)

So we see based off the Gemara in Pesachim that rather than conclude the bracha with all the avos, we only do so with Avraham.

The Maharal in [Gur Aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Bereishit.12.2.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) helps provide a reason why:

> בך חותמין כו'. ואם תאמר מאחר שכלם אבות למה לא יחתום בכולם, ואין זה קשיא, דאין חותמין בשתים, כדאמרינן במסכת ברכות (מט.). ואם תאמר מאי שנא אברהם, נראה מפני שהבן בכח האב ואין האב בכח הבן, ולכך בחתימת אברהם יש חתימה יצחק ויעקב. ואלו דברים הם אמת למבינים, והוא דבר נעלם
>
> With you (i.e. Just Avraham's name) they conclude the Bracha etc. And if you will say since they are all fathers why not sign off with them all (i.e. say Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaakov)? And this is not a problem, since we do not conclude with two (themes). Like we say in [Brachos 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.49a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and if you say how is Avraham different it would seem that the son is in the power of the father and the father is not in the power of the son , and therefore included in the signing off of Avraham is both Yitzchak and Yaakov. And these words are true to those who understand them and it is a hidden matter.

So my questions are as follows:

1. How are the individual Avos to be regarded as a separate themes? Surely, whilst they embodied different core middos e.g. Avraham - chesed, Yitzchak - gevurah and Yaakov - emes/Torah they **all** still represent the concept of being our forebears, i.e. the Patriarchs who established the standard for us all?
2. And if we say like the Maharal that the 'son is in the power of the father' and thus Avraham encompasses all of them - why then do we make a point of starting the bracha mentioning all three. Surely there too we could just say Avraham?

Comment: This question relates to how one is to have proper intentions for each of these four different categories. It is about the four different permutations of G-d’s names. Three of those permutations are specific to each of the three Avot. The fourth name is the source, “אב”, to the three names associated with the three Avot. Both Rashi and the Maharal are alluding to this fourth name. That fourth name is the name intended when saying אל עליון. Are you familiar with this subject?

Comment: @YaacovDeane - please forgive my ignorance. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The Rokeach says that we mention all three because they established our three daily prayers. Perhaps for your Q2: in the body, where we can mention all three, we do, but in the ḥatima, where we *can't* mention all three (assuming a sensible answer to your Q1), we choose Avraham.

Comment: @magicker72 - thank you feel free to write and source this in an answer and I'd be happy to upvote :-)

Comment: @magicker72 That may go against https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126315/759 since we mention all three in non-daily prayers too (no reason the rokeach and noda bihuda need to agree of course)

Comment: @Dov There are specific letter transformations of the Shem HaMeforash that are associated/attributed to each of the Avot. Those transformed names are what one intends (as in Kavanah) when saying the blessing for each of the Avot. There is a 4th name also intended that corresponds to the phrase אל עליון, which is different.  These 4 names are also intended in reverse order with the expression, "מלך עוזר ומושיע ומגן", with 'Magen' corresponding to Avraham. That 4th name also has 3 other associated names which are all related to the manifestation of Malchut. 3 for the Avot and 4 for the Imahot.

Comment: @Dov To clarify: These 4 names (associated with the Avot & the additional name) are also intended in reverse order with the expression, "מלך עוזר ומושיע ומגן", with 'Magen' corresponding to Avraham, 'Moshiah' to Yitzchok and 'Ozair' to Yaacov. That 4th name (related to אל עליון) also has 3 other associated names which are all related to the manifestation of Malchut. So in the opening blessings of the Amidah one has intention corresponding to the 7 name transformations, 3 for the Avot and 4 for the Imahot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe, but since it doesn't say אלהי אברהם שחידש שחרית אלהי יצחק שחידש מנחה ואלהי יעקב שחידש מעריב, it could very well be generic enough that even the Noda Bihuda could agree with the Rokeaḥ.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your  second question, the answer is that all the Avos are separate, and deserve to be mentioned separately. However,  it is not possible to mention them all in the closing, so we mention the one that includes the most, which is Avraham.

Comment: " it is not possible to mention them all in the closing" why not?

Comment: The Gur Aryeh quotes the Gemara as saying that, in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the *binyan* (structure) of *Chesed*, *Gevurah* and *Emes*, *Chesed* is a "child element", not an *av*. I.e. *chesed* is not intrinsically associated with the *koach ha'holadah* (power to father/beget). This is because *chesed* implies there is happiness/fulfilment in the current state so there is no need to be *molid* (beget future generations). Therefore the *koach ha'avhus* of Avraham Avinu (that which he was a "Father" to the Jewish people) is not a *toldah* (derivative) of his *middas ha'chesed*.

From this perspective, Yitzchak and Yaakov were not *toldos* (derivatives) of Avraham's *middas ha'chesed*. Rather each created anew their own *derech* (way) in serving Hashem. That is why each is mentioned separately in the *berachah*. However, from the perspective of *koach gufa*, i.e. from the perspective that is was Avraham who had the perspicacity, endurance and strength to found the Jewish people, Yitzchak and Yaakov are included in Avraham, because that is where they got their own perspicacity from.

Therefore we can conceive of the entity of the Jewish people in two ways. We can consider the Jewish people to be a coalescing of the individual avodah of each of the *avos* or we can consider the Jewish people to come entirely from the *koach* of Avraham.

Relative to the second perspective, we are *mesayem* (complete the first blessing of Shemone Esrei) with just Avraham, as he is the *amud ha'kol* (foundation of everything). Relative to the first perspective, we mention each *av* separately within the *berachah*.

Answer (score 0):

The [Midrash Shocher Tov/Tehillim 18:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.18.25?lang=bi) notes that what stands Avraham apart, is Hashem refined him through 10 tests:

> דבר אחר האל תמים דרכו. זה אברהם שנאמר (בראשית יז א) התהלך לפני והיה תמים. אמרת ה' צרופה. שצרפו הקב"ה בעשר נסיונות. ואלו הן - כשירד לתוך כבשן האש שנאמר (שם טו ז) אני ה' אשר הוצאתיך מאור כשדים. שנים כשאמר לו לך לך. ושנים בשרה. בהגר (שם טז ב) בא נא אל שפחתי. ובישמעאל (שם כא י) גרש האמה הזאת. ובמלכים (שם יד יד) וירק את חניכיו. ובמילה שאמר לו הקב"ה (שם יז א) התהלך לפני והיה תמים. ובין הבתרים כשראה המלכיות משעבדות לבניו. וביצחק (שם כב ב) קח נא את בנך את יחידך. הוי אמרת ה' צרופה מגן הוא. אומות העכו"ם אומרים למה הקב"ה מחבב לאברהם הצילו מכבשן האש ומן תשעה מלכים ואוכלוסין ומכל הצרות שעברו עליו. אמר להן הקב"ה הריני אומר לו שיקריב את בנו והוא שומע לי וחוסה בי לפיכך אני מגינו. הוי מגן הוא לכל החוסים בו. ולמחר מברכין בניו בתפלה ברוך מגן אברהם.
>
> Another thing: God's way is perfect. This refers to Abraham, as it says, "And when Abram was ninety years old and nine, the LORD appeared to Abram, and said unto him, I am the Almighty God; walk before me, and be thou perfect." (Genesis 17:1) You have said, "The LORD is a shield." This means that the Lord refined Abraham through ten trials. These are: when he was thrown into the fiery furnace, as it says, "I am the LORD who brought you out of Ur of the Chaldeans" (Genesis 15:7); twice when God told him to go, and twice with Sarah, in Gerar when he said, "Come to my handmaid" (Genesis 16:2), with Ishmael when he sent away Hagar, and when he smote the kings (Genesis 14:14); and when God said to him, "Walk before me, and be thou perfect" (Genesis 17:1). And during the latter trials, when he saw that the kingdoms were enslaving his descendants, and in Isaac, when God said, "Take now thy son, thine only son Isaac" (Genesis 22:2). Therefore, you have said, "The LORD is a shield" for all who seek refuge in Him. The nations of the world ask, "Why did God love Abraham so much, that He saved him from the fiery furnace, from nine kings and populations, and from all the troubles that he experienced?" God replied, "I am saying to him, 'Sacrifice your son,' and he listens to me and trusts in me. Therefore, I shield him. He is a shield for all who trust in Him." And tomorrow, his children will bless him in prayer, saying, "Blessed be the shield of Abraham...

The [Shelah HaKadosh, Torah Shebichsav, Lech Lecha, Torah Ohr](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Lech_Lecha%2C_Torah_Ohr.41?lang=bi) provides a more Kabbalistic answer, that the closing of the bracha in Avraham's name is because he is regarded as the "father" of all of them:

> והגם שהאבות הם מרכבה (בר"ר מז, ו), מכל מקום אברהם אבינו שהוא אב הראשון הוא כולל כלם, על כן חתימתו מגן אברהם, כי מגן הם שרי מרכבה דמדריגת האבות חסד גבורה תפארת כדפירשתי.
>
> Although all the patriarchs have been described as the מרכבה (see [Bereishis Rabbah 47:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.47.6?lang=bi)), they are all included when Abraham is mentioned; he, being the "father" of them all, represents them also. This is the reason that the first benediction in the daily עמידה prayer concludes with the signature מגן אברהם, "shield of Abraham." The term "shield" is used to describe those who support the מרכבה, namely חסד, גבורה, תפארת.